# Using "would have" + past participle in conditional clauses

Tags: grammar, conditional-constructions

Can I use *"would have" + past participle* structure for conditional clauses?

> For many years he would practice that kind of style of management,
>   that is, not getting into the details of problems much and even
>   deliberately staying unaware of them. On one hand, it saved him a lot
>   of free time for his personal pursuits outside of the work setting,
>   and, on the other hand, if worse ***would have come*** to the worst,
>   he would have always been able to put the blame on those who “failed
>   to inform him in timely and amply manner”.

In the passage above I don't know what structure to use in the conditional clause.

Saying "***if worse had come to the worst***" would mean that I refer to some event that had already happened prior to what is described in the passage, but in the passage by "the worst" I am trying to refer to some possible event that might have taken later, that is, after the earlier event described in the passage had already started (that is, after the action of practicing a certain style of management had already started and lasted for a while).

"***If worse came to the worst***", as far as I know, just like ***"if worse comes to the worst"*** refers to a possible event in the present time, that is, the time of narration of the passage, but my passage is in the past and all the events that are talked about in it are the events that either happened or could have happened long before the time of narration.

However, "***if worse would have come to the worst***" results in using "would have" in both clauses, which is probably redundant.

Comment: In BrE the use of 'would' in such conditional clauses sounds odd, as if the speaker were translating literally from some other language (German maybe?). "if worse came to worse" would be the usual way of expressing the thought.